# Influx DB 2 api token use in different container

Tags: docker, influxdb, docker-secrets

I want to create an read only influx API token when initializing my influx DB using [this command](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/reference/cli/influx/auth/create/#create-a-read-only-api-token). I want to have the resulting API key of this call available as a docker secret so other containers can use it. My problem is that this command seems only to be able to generate a new API and not to set one that I pass to it (which is what I want). (For the `setup` command you are able to pass the token.)

Is there any option I am missing that is able to do this or is there any way to get the resulting API available to the the other containers via docker secrets that are using it?

Thanks